# obtener el elemento seleccionado desde un DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo html que despliega una lista de elementos.

```html
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Product</label>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId, Model.ProductsList, new { @data_placeholder = "Select Product...", @data_parsley_required = "true" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

necesito en javascript obtener el elemento seleccionado, para pasar este parametro a traves de una llamada ajax a un controller.

como se logra obtener el id del elemento seleccionado?
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas crear una especie de controlador el cual solo te devuelva el id y el nombre de lo que quieres mostrar.
Con eso llenas tu dropdawnList
y posteriormente lo obtienes en el metodo on selecteditemchanged si estas en C# codebehind o si es atravez de jquery con lo siguiente 
$('#id').value();
Suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias. por el dato